# Convert JavaScript Array of Objects to Array of Values in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, rest

I want this

```
 [{ prop1: '100', prop2: false, prop3: null, prop4: 'abc' },
  { prop1: '102', prop2: false, prop3: null, prop4: 'def' } 
   ]
```

to be converted to this

```
[[100,false,null,'abc'] , [102,false,null,'def']]
```

in Node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `map` the array by taking `Object values` of the object.

```js
const array =  [{ prop1: '100', prop2: false, prop3: null, prop4: 'abc' }, { prop1: '102', prop2: false, prop3: null, prop4: 'def' }];

const result = array.map(item=>Object.values(item));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` func to generate a new array result.

```js
const data = [
  { prop1: '100', prop2: false, prop3: null, prop4: 'abc' },
  { prop1: '102', prop2: false, prop3: null, prop4: 'def' }
];

let result = data.reduce((acc: any, item: any) => {
  acc.push(Object.values(item));

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```